# Динамический массив как параметр функции

Tags: c++, функции, указатели, динамические-массивы, теория

Для добавления элемента в динамический массив увидел такой синтаксис:

```
void push_back(int*& arr, int &size, int val)
{
    int* newArr = new int[size + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        newArr[i] = arr[i];
    }
    newArr[size] = val;
    size++;
    delete[] arr;
    arr = newArr;
}
```

Вопрос касается передачи самого массива в качестве параметра, автор видео использует указатель на ссылку `*&`, почему не работает передача массива по указателю?
Не могу понять что именно происходит при передаче указателя на ссылку, разве при передаче по указателю мы не можем так же заменить адрес на который указывает указатель?

Comment: Ссылки на указатель, а не указателя на ссылку...

Comment: потому что внутри функции значение указателя меняется. Если передать просто как `int* arr`, то передается копия значения указателя (но не копия того, на что он указывает) и это точно также как передавать `int a` в функцию и потом говорить, почему оно не меняется по выходу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ключевой момент здесь в последней строчке:

```
arr = newArr;
```

Здесь переменной arr присваивается значение нового указателя, а arr - это параметр функции, который передается по ссылке. Поэтому значение переменной arr (то есть самого указателя, адреса на участок памяти) изменится и в вызывающем коде тоже.

Этот код делает следующее:

1. Выделяет память под новый массив, размер которого на единицу больше исходного;
2. Копирует исходный массив в новый;
3. Дописывает в конец нового массива добавляемое значение;
4. Удаляет исходный массив;
5. Заменяет указатель на исходный массив указателем на новый массив. Замена отработает и в вызывающем коде тоже, так как указатель передан по ссылке.

> разве при передаче по указателю мы не можем так же заменить адрес на который указывает указатель?

Нет, не можем. При передаче по указателю мы можем изменить тот участок памяти, на который этот указатель указывает, но не сам указатель (адрес). Замену самого адреса можно провести либо с помощью передачи указателя по ссылке (как в вашем примере), либо при передаче указателя по указателю: `int **arr`. Во втором случае при замене адреса его нужно будет разыменовывать:

```
*arr = newArr;
```

Comment: Писал почти то же... Ссылка нужна, чтобы, как минимум, освобождать память  по переданному указателю

Comment: то-есть если передавать только сам указатель в функцию func(*arr), то получается так, что где-то в памяти по другому адресу создаётся такой же массив arr и мы работаем с ним и ничего не меняется за пределами функции, а func(*& arr) производит работу с оригинальным адресом arr и данными на который он указывает в памяти и в итоге можем его поменять и всё работает как нужно?

прошу прощения если переписал ваш ответ, просто хочу точно понять, а то моск плавится..

Comment: @VadimDidenko, нет, в функцию передается ровно то, что указано в её параметрах. Если передать в функцию указатель на массив, то нигде не создаётся копия этого массива. Создаётся только копия его адреса (одного числа). Зная это число, функция может внести изменения в содержимое массива, которые отразятся в вызывающем коде. Но она не может изменить сам адрес, так как работает с его локальной копией. Чтобы заменить сам адрес, чтобы он указывал уже на другой массив, надо передать его по ссылке.

Comment: Благодарю, вроде дошло

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, для освобождения памяти ссылка не нужна. Нужен указатель на массив, который ранее был аллоцирован оператором new.

Comment: @maestro, указатель в функции уже указывает на новый участок памяти. Как будет вызывающая функция освобождать эту память?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, а, вы имели в виду, как *вызывающий* код будет освобождать. Тогда верно, если передать указатель в функцию по значению, то получится утечка памяти и двойное удаление.

Comment: ну да, а что еще я мог иметь ввиду? По мне я ясно выразился в первом комментарии...